# Apply Master Data Services to an existing SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm familiar with creating MDS databases once MDS is installed, but is it possible to install/enable/configure MDS for databases that existed prior to the installation of MDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unaware of any way to "apply" MDS to an existing database. A possible migration strategy is to recreate the database schema as an MDS model and use the entity based staging feature to migrate data from the original database to the MDS model. Here's a primer on EBS and how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/hh802433.aspx.